# AFNetworking why parse server's json?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I use `AFNetworking` request server, but I get output like this:

```
2012-12-25 15:16:47.578 SmsForNewYear[3825:c07] <3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 432f2f44 54442058 48544d4c 20312e30 20547261 6e736974 696f6e61 6c2f2f45 4e222022 68747470 3a2f2f77 77772e77 332e6f72
```

It's not json, if I add `[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];`

It returns:

```
SmsForNewYear[3920:c07] getNewSms:Expected content type {(
"text/json",
"application/json",
"text/javascript"
)}, got text/html
```

But I used browser, it looks this

```
{"rs_code":"200","data":{"sms_cate_list":[{"id":"26","name":"\u559c\u5e86","likes":"0","sms_num":"1","order_id":"1","is_index":"0","update_time":"1355932115"}
```

It is json.

on the other hand, i use `asihttprequest` can return json.

why?

Comment: Incidentally, decoding that `NSData`, it looks like it's a start of an HTML response (but there's not enough here to see what it says). When you `NSLog` the `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData]`, it will be interesting to see what it is, but it could be an error message about the URL being wrong or something like that.

Comment: thanks,i found the wrong, it's no rest style ,i write like this [AFSmsAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"sn=sms.sms.display"
                              parameters:nil
, it is look like facebook style , so sn=sms.sms.display is get method's parameter

Comment: Cool. It was impossible to diagnose on the basis of the `NSLog` of the `NSData`. I initially assumed (incorrectly) that it might have been a valid JSON response, but upon further inspection, it was clear that there was some error being reported by the server (but the `NSData` that you included was not enough to diagnose it because it was getting cut off). Anyway, good you found it. In the future, if you get a server response in a `NSData` object, converting it to a `NSString` like I outline below will help you diagnose the problem much more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Your first `NSLog` is a typical `NSData` log result, which is hard to read. If you want to look at it for debugging purposes, you can

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Obviously replace `jsonData` with whatever variable is holding that `NSData` object. You can examine that before you declare failure.

When I decode the `NSData` string that you logged, it appears to be the start of a HTML file, so I bet your web server is reporting an error. You'll have to look at the `NSString` version of that HTML to figure out what the problem is (you haven't included enough for us to diagnose, as the `NSLog` of the `NSData` is cutting off the result prematurely).

In terms of diagnosing the problem, you have to show us the message generated by the above `NSLog`. You probably also need to show us your `AFNetworking` code where you make the request of the web service.

---

Generally when you download data from a web server, when you `NSLog` the `NSData` result, you'll see something cryptic like this. You can then, quite happily, pass to `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];
if (error != nil)
    NSLog(@"Error in JSON: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: [[AFSmsAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"sn=sms.sms.display"
                              parameters:nil
                                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
                                   NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);}  i through this to found this wrong.